# Getting startup time in Windows 10 doesn't give always the same time

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I'm using this python (3.5) code to check windows startup time but it gives me a different time from the time I get using the shell command "systeminfo"

- systeminfo: 9:15:23
- python code: 9:14:42

Not happy with that, the python code is giving different times in itself!
It started giving me 9:14:42, and right now it gives me 9:15:19, it's been adding a second to the boot time every 10 seconds or so.

I give you the code:

```
import datetime
import win32api

s = win32api.GetTickCount()
t = datetime.datetime.now()
st = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=s)
bt = t-st
boot = "Boot time was around {}:{}:{}".format(bt.hour, bt.minute, bt.second)
print(boot)
```

I'm starting to think about calling the systeminfo command from python and just show the time it gives me.

Comment: GetTickCount does not report the startup time. To get that use WMI: http://superuser.com/questions/523726/how-can-i-find-out-when-windows-was-last-restarted

Comment: I've been reading about wmi and now I get the same time, just a few times it is a second ahead the time given by systeminfo, but it should be because it's not possible to take the timestamp at the same second( or millisecond) and it shows itself in that second more or less, but it's acceptable.  Edit: (Can't press Enter to say thanks... ) Thanks!!

Comment: @fdzworkzone answers should not go in the question. If you've come up with a different solution, then you should post it as its own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>taken from [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058372/getting-startup-time-in-windows-10-doesnt-give-always-the-same-time#comment59763939_36058372) and [question edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36058372/2)</sub>

`GetTickCount` does not report the startup time. To get that you should be using [WMI](https://superuser.com/questions/523726/how-can-i-find-out-when-windows-was-last-restarted)

```
import datetime
import wmi

wmiob = wmi.WMI()
sdata = wmiob.Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_System()
uptime = sdata[-1].SystemUpTime
tnow = datetime.datetime.now()
utime = datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(uptime))
boot = tnow-utime
bootime = "Boot time was around {}:{}:{}".format(boot.hour, boot.minute, boot.second)
print(bootime)
```